# Filtering data to an exact match in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, typeahead

I am using React Select. I realized that with an input value it only returns the items that have that value included in their string (order does not matter). I would like to change it so that those that match the input string more closely are sorted at the top ex: if I type Veteran it shouldn't return Organization of veterans, Veterans community. It should return the second one first. I am not the best with javascript so please explain as much as you can.

```js
const AutoComplete = (props) => {
const filterOrgs = async (inputValue) => {
let array = []
await getOrgs(inputValue)
  .then(res=>{
    setLocalStorage(res)
    return res.map(i=>array.push({label:i.site_name}))
  })
  return getValues(array, inputValue)
};

const promiseOptions = inputValue => 
new Promise(resolve => {
  inputValue = inputValue.charAt(0).toUpperCase()
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(filterOrgs(inputValue));
    }, 1000);
  });

  const setLocalStorage=(data)=>{
    return localStorage.setItem(1, JSON.stringify(data))
  }

  const getValues=(array,inputValue)=>{
      return array.slice(0,10).filter(i =>
      i.label.toLowerCase().includes(inputValue.toLowerCase())
    )
  }

    return (
      <AsyncSelect cacheOptions defaultOptions loadOptions={promiseOptions} className='asyncSelect' id='asyncType' name={props.name} onChange={props.handleChange}/>
    );
  
}

export default AutoComplete;
```

Comment: What do you mean matches more closely? They both match exactly because they have Veteran in their names. What is the criteria for a "close match" here?

Comment: Apologies for not being clear, basically, if the input value is Veteran, it should sort the data and return the results where the Veteran is the first word in the drop down select then as you go lower and lower it is less specific like it's included somewhere in the string. So if I typed like Veteran's in Connecticut, it should return all the ones that match that input first on the top of the returned data.

Comment: I've added an answer based on your specifics. It's probably not exactly correct but the general idea should be easy to grasp and manipulate.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, your filter in getValues uses the `.includes(...)` and `.slice(0,10)` methods to filter organizations. This will return an array of the top 10 filtered organizations matching your criteria.

If you want to have your array sorted differently, then you should use the `sort` method and implement your custom sort behavior here.

So, your new get values will look like this:

```
  const getValues=(array,inputValue)=>{
      return array.slice(0,10).filter(i =>
      i.label.toLowerCase().includes(inputValue.toLowerCase())
      .sort((org1, org2) => {
           // can't remember the real syntax here if we need a return or not...
           // you may also need to swap the directions of the subtraction here. 
           // the key is to use indexOf to find the index where the substring is located in your match and compare in a custom sort.
           org1.indexOf(inputValue.toLowerCase()) - org2.indexOf(inputValue.toLowerCase());
      })
    )
  }
```

Again, so you can see how this array is being manipulated almost in a beautiful order. First slice, then filter the slice, then sort the sliced and filtered array.

```
  const getValues = (array, inputValue) => {
    return array
      .slice(0, 10)
      .filter((i) => i.label.toLowerCase().includes(inputValue.toLowerCase()))
      .sort(...);
  };
```

Links for your reference:

- https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_array_sort.asp
- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp

Comment: Hey, I see where you're getting at but I think at my skill level I still would not be able to know what logic to put in the sort to make this happen to be honest.

Comment: Have you tried the code yet? That's basically exactly what you need. You may need to flip the org1 and org2 in the sort itself. You won't get better unless you try, and I've provided and almost full answer for you to start with.

Comment: I got distracted with another post saying that react select has an API for this: 
https://react-select.com/advanced
I tried using it and it works really well. Just one thing though, by adding this, when I type veteran, because nothing in my data starts with veteran but has it included it brings back no results. I am trying to see if you can make it so that it will pull in the matchFrom start values first then the matchFrom:any values after it

Comment: If you had results from the array in your example, then the sort doesn't remove any results, it just sorts the array you get back. Check if your original has any results before making the sort.

Comment: There is data in the results. Data comes back with the original logic I have in place. When I add yours, it returns nothing. How does it know what org1 and org2 is if I do not pass in those values?

Comment: similar to the filter function where you use i without declaring it or passing it in, basically sort assumes those parameters to be values in the array, just like filter assumes i to be a value in the array and iterates through all the values held in the array. that's odd that the sort removes results.

Comment: I see, but I do not know why it returns nothing. It should I am assuming but it says no results on the front end. am I doing something wrong here? I incorporated it just as you said. Also, if I do not return what is inside sort I get "Expected an assignment or function call, instead saw an expression" and when I do I get no results basically...

Comment: Try removing the brackets {} in the sort so on the line you add it just says .sort((org1, org2) => org1... - org2....);

Comment: const getValues=(array,inputValue)=>{
      return array.slice(0,10).filter(i =>
      i.label.toLowerCase().includes(inputValue.toLowerCase()).sort((org1, org2) => org1.indexOf(inputValue.toLowerCase()) - org2.indexOf(inputValue.toLowerCase()))
    )
  }

That is what I have and I get No Options on the front end...

Comment: Right now I think the sort...it's WITHIN the filter, so that's why its affecting the filter. You need to bring it outside the filter so it sorts after the filter. It kind of reads like a real sentence, first filter, then sort. So place the .sort after the closing parentheses of the .filter. I will add my answer so this is a bit more clear for your needs.

Comment: Okay so now it worked but it did absolutely nothing. The same results come back. I type in Employer and the ones that start with employer come after some that do not start with it but have it in the string. It's exactly as it was before is what I am trying to say.

Comment: Try flipping the org2 and org1 in the sort

Comment: I did and same results come back

Comment: In your program, can you try logging the array after its fully sorted before you use the value of the array to display in front end? See if the array is displaying in sorted order in your log. Something else in your front end may be affecting the display of elements from the array. So just use console.log(array) in the right position. Flip org1 and org2 and see what the log result is.

Comment: The data is massive but I do not see it changing the data. I can't seem to log it without changing a bunch of code cause it is like 3000 items in the data

Comment: What do you mean? Not logging data but just logging the result array right before you display it. It should have a max of 10 elements since we slice the top 10.

Comment: const getValues=(array,inputValue)=>{
      array.slice(0,10).filter(i =>
      i.label.toLowerCase().includes(inputValue.toLowerCase())
    )
    .sort((org1, org2) =>{
    return  org2.label.indexOf(inputValue.toLowerCase()) - org1.label.indexOf(inputValue.toLowerCase())
    })
    console.log(array)
    return array
  }
Correct?

Comment: You can try logging there, it will log multiple times, once for every time the function is called that console.log is called in. See at the top where you call getValues()? That's where the array is being sorted and filtered and that sorted and filtered value is set and returned. You need to try something like let testarray = getValues(); then console.log(testarray). then return testarray. You could also just put that entire await block in a giant console.log() since it seems to return an array that can be printed.

Comment: I think using the API kinda did the trick and got me closer to my result without overcomplication. Thank you